# df.show() (and joins) missing data that is present when running same code from client mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm facing a strange issue in Spark.
I'm trying to read data from Delta Lake using:

```
df = spark.read \
        .format("delta") \
        .load(path)
```

Then I try to filter the same using an ID:

```
df2 = df.where(f"entityId=={entity_id}")
```

When I print the count:

```
print(df2.count())
```

It comes out to be `1` under both Client Mode and Cluster Mode.

But when I try to do:

```
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

I get **no results** when I run the same in Cluster mode.
Contrastingly, the complete row gets printed in Client Mode.

This is not happening for all records; Only some of them.

What could be the issue here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On Spark WebUI, check what is your driver host when you submit in cluster mode and check stdout for that host. In client mode, the host from where you issue `spark-submit` becomes your driver host but in cluster mode, Spark internally selects one from all the available worker nodes.

Comment: An unusual link to make.